# Cant use product in Haskell

Tags: haskell, product

I want run this (primelist = list of all the primes, translate = give me a lsit of number):

```hs
encode :: Dictionary -> String -> Integer
encode ((a,b):xs) (y:ys) = product zipWith (^) [n | n <-primeList] [m | m<-translate ((a,b):xs) (y:ys)]
```

I get:

```
Couldn't match type `[c0]' with `[Integer] -> [Integer]' problem
```

Comment: share the `primeList` and the `translate` functions? A `Dictionary` is a list of 2-tuples? Why do you use `(a, b):xs` as pattern? This means it will not match the empty list. The same for `y:ys`.

Comment: Your expression will also need parenthesis, right now `product` takes `zipWith` as first parameter. It should be `product (zipWith (^) primeList (translate ((a,b):xs) (y:ys)))`, but then likely without these patterns.

Comment: `f (g x y)` calls `f` with one argument, `f g x y` calls `f` with _three_ arguments. Add proper parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the lack of parenthesis. Now `product` takes `zipWith` as parameter, not the result of `zipWith (^) …`. Another problem that can pop up is that the patterns will only work if both the `Dictionary` and the `String` are non-empty. It is also not necessary to use list comprehension here: `[ n | n <- primeList ]` is equivalent to `primeList`:

```
encode :: Dictionary -> String -> Integer
encode ds ys = product (zipWith (^) primeList (translate ds ys))
```

The `translate ds ys` needs to produce a list of numbers of the `Integral` type, so for example a list of `Integer`s.